# SSH - Can't connect from LAN after switching to another network

Tags: raspbian, wifi, ssh, remote, connection

A couple of days ago I bought a new raspberry pi 4, for now, I don't have desktop support but I set it up in headless mode (installed raspbian on sd card).

I was able to connect it using ssh when it was using my old router (192.168.**1**.xx was my pi's address)
now I am using a different network(192.168.**43**.xx) which is a mobile hotspot and I can't connect to ssh, nmap shows that all ports are filtered (-Pn)

fortunately, I had tor hidden service set up and I am able to connect to the onion address, but this is not comfortable at all

is there anyone who had a similar issue? and what would be a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Pi problem.

Devices used as hotspots generally DO NOT allow through connections. Similar issues arise using Internet Connection Sharing on a PC.

Comment: I am able to connect to a laptop that is connected to a hotspot as well, is there any way to connect it remotely?